# JavaScript Shorthand for a jQuery If-Else Snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, shorthand

I have this snippet of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    if(!$.browser.msie){ 
        $('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    } else if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('#myDiv').css({opacity:1});
    }
}); 
</script>
```

How can I say the same thing using the `" : something ? somethingElse "` syntax?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: Don't use ternary operators as a generic if/else. Use them for simple assignments, that is what they are designed for. Real if/else across more lines are more readable. Embrace readability over code golf.

Comment: The long and short of it is you probably don't want to. Nested ternary syntax gets very ugly.

Comment: ... also the `else if ($.browser.msie) {` is redundant. A simple `else {` would be enough.

Comment: I agree with you 100%, guys, but in this case I actually do need the "code golf", for a certain reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure I got the question, however:

```
$.browser.msie ? $('#myDiv').css({opacity: 1}) : $('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
```

Also, I'm not an expert of IE anymore, but I wonder if you could do something like:

```
$('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, $.browser.msie ? 0 : 300);
```

That should be applied immediately, and made it more readable with an external variable:

```
var speed = $.browser.msie ? 0 : 300;
$('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, speed);
```

Or something like that.

Comment: @ZERO, this is awesome! I LOVE the idea of using var. The best of both worlds!

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work means? How IE behave with this code? As I said I'm not an IE expert anymore, because I don't use this browser for my job, but in other browser the code behaves as expected – with speed `0` the changes is immediate.

Comment: I tried and it works for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/smJaD The only thing here is that `$.browser` is deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9, so you have to use another version. But that is true with all solution that uses `$.browser`.

Comment: In my case I tried with `mozilla` instead of `msie`, so using Firefox makes it visible immediately without animation; and others is displayed with the animation.

Comment: The first version worked exactly in `$(function() {…})`, I added a button just to control the process. You can test on codepen too. Again, it could be that IE misbehave somehow, I don't know, but you said "doesn't appear at all in any browser", and in that case I'm pretty sure it worked. :)

Comment: Ehe, in page where you used the code I proposed, you forgot to actually wrap it on `$(window).load(function() {…}` that's why it doesn't work: `$('#gallery')` is executed too soon when the element is not loaded yet probably, that's why you don't see anything. Just wrap the code in the `$(window).load(function() {…}` and everything should works as the other version.

Comment: @ZERO -- I figured it out! I had opacity set to 0, instead of 1. You're the best, and I was wrong. It is working!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.browser.msie ? $('#myDiv').css({opacity:1}); : $('#myDiv').animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
});
```

I wouldn't *recommend* it for at least two reasons (browser sniffing, and readability), but you *can*.

Another way:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#myDiv')[$.browser.msie ? 'css' : 'animate']({opacity:1}, $.browser.msie ? undefined : 300);
});
```

...but that's even worse. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the point about not recommending it, I just needed to know how this can be done.

Comment: May I ask, @T.J. Crowder, why ae you against browser sniffing in this case?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov: I'm not against browser sniffing in this case specifically, I'm opposed to it *generally*. :-) There's almost (*almost*) always a better option (feature sniffing, for instance).

Comment: Ok, @T.J. Crowder, then maybe you could suggest a solution (I'd be grateful): I'm sniffing the browser because IE does a lousy job animating png transparancy. #myDiv in this case contains a png image with transparency. What would you do?

Comment: @DimitriVorontzov: Dunno, I've never animated png transparency. :-) But consider: What if IE10 does a really good job of it? But yes, behaviors like that can be hard to sniff. Kangax has a great list here: http://kangax.github.com/cft/ You never know, sometimes things are more sniffable than they seem.

Comment: LOL, there's always a first time.

Comment: By the way, @T.J. Crowder, there's a ; in the first of your examples that disables the code, after the first $('#myDiv').css({opacity:1}); – it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @T.J. Crowder, it's a useful resource!